# Symfony6 login with memory user provider

Tags: authentication, symfony, memory, symfony6

I try to [login with a symfony's memory user provider with the official doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall).

So i make my user with `symfony console make:user`, i let defaults and chose "no" to using database.

I add my adminuser in `security.yaml` and some configuration :

```json
security:
  password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: "auto"
  providers:
    app_user_provider:
      id: App\Security\UserProvider
    backend_users:
      memory:
        users:
          my:
            {
              password: "$2y$…B3", // i put my true bcrypt generated password
              roles: ["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"],
            }
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      lazy: true
      provider: app_user_provider
  access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
when@test:
  security:
    password_hashers:
      Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
        time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
        memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

I make login action :

```php
    #[Route('/{_locale<%app.supported_locales%>}/login', name: 'my_login')]
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
        return $this->render('@MyCore/Core/login.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'CoreController',
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ]);
    }
```

With associated form as in the doc :

```html
{% extends '@MyCore/layout-default.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('my_login') }}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}"/>

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password"/>

        {# If you want to control the URL the user is redirected to on success
                <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account"/> #}

        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">

        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

And… Nothing happen. When i try to login, with true user or random false entry, there is no error, no logging, just i go back to "/login" as if nothing happened.

Did i forget something ?

**EDIT**

Yes, i simply forget something : to define the `login_form` in `security.yaml` (shame on me, i could delete but, maybe someone will do the same error and search so…) :

```json
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                login_path: my_login
                check_path: my_login
            logout:
                path: my_logout
```

Comment: What does the log file say? There should be some `ERROR` or `CRITICAL` line...

Comment: i have error : `app.ERROR: error while trying to collect executed migrations {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\DriverException(code: 0)`, but i have it from the beginning as i dont use/need any related database entity yet.

Comment: Did you by any chance specify the wrong database credentials? And why did you specify `provider: app_user_provider` in your firewall config?

Comment: I don't have database yet. I don't need. It's why i want to use memory user provider.
`provider: app_user_provider` is added by the command `make:user`.

Comment: There may be another issue with the route you're using in the `form`. The route name is mistyped (`mty_login` instead of `my_login`).

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich, it's just a typo in my question. The route is correct and here is the $_POST : `"_username" => "fdgfgfsd",  "_password" => "sgfsgfs",  "_csrf_token" => "e4fzA",  "action" => ""`

Comment: For information, the error with database in the previous log as definitly nothing to do with the problem, i installed a brand new fresh symfony6.1, without any error, just for trying the login with 1 memory user and it's the same : nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to specify the login form in `security.yaml` :

```
security:
  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
  password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: "auto"
  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
  providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
      id: App\Security\UserProvider
    backend_users:
      memory:
        users:
          my_user:
            {
              password: "%env(USER_PASSWORD)%",
              roles: ["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"],
            }
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      lazy: true
      provider: backend_users
      form_login:
        login_path: my_login
        check_path: my_login
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no firewall configured to use your `backend_users` user provider.

If you want to use your in-memory users for the `main` firewall configure it as follows:

```yaml
security:
  # [..]
  providers:
    backend_users:
      memory:
        users: [] # <- add your users here
  firewalls:
    main:
      lazy: true
      provider: backend_users # <- use the provider here
```

Comment: It changes nothing. I changed prodider from `app_user_provider` to `backend_users`, nothing happens… No error, no logging. Nothing happens…

Comment: Don't forget to clear your cache `bin/console cache:clear` after any changes to security configuration. Setting the provider correctly is a requirement for any authentication to work :)

Comment: I cleared the cache. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the *app_user_provider* but your need to use 2 providers, the *app_user_provider* and the *backend_users* provider in same time. To build this you need to use a provider chain ([Symfony Doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_providers.html#chain-user-provider)) :

```yaml
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    # ...
    providers:
        backend_users:
            # ...

        app_user_provider:
            # ...

        all_users:
            chain:
                providers: ['backend_users', 'app_user_provider']
    firewalls:
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: all_users # all_users => provider chain
```

Comment: Doesn't works better. Nothing happens. No error, no alert, no authentification.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from your security configration. If you need to add two users then you should use a chain, take a look at Symfony docs.

Comment: I don't need 2 users. I just need that admin memory user.

Anyway, i just tryed chain and it changes nothing : no error, no alert, nothing happens.

Here is the log :
`[2022-09-26T15:52:54.226530+02:00] request.INFO: Matched route "my_login". {"route":"my_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"my_login","_controller":"My\\CoreBundle\\Controller\\CoreController::login","_locale":"fr"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/fr/login","method":"POST"} []
[2022-09-26T15:52:54.227351+02:00] security.DEBUG: Checking for authenticator support. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticators":0} []`